# OpenCV Threshold with mask in circle shape

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

By using OpenCV, I am trying to black out the image except for specific points. 
I want to apply the threshold with a mask in a circle shape.
But I don't know how to do this, I'm a beginner in OpenCV.

Here is my code.

```
DrawCircle(String filename, int x, int y, int radius) {

    Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread(filename);

    Mat gray = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(src, gray, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    Imgproc.threshold(gray,gray,255,255,0);

    // Save results
    File rs1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/result.png");
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(rs1.toString(), gray);

}
```

This is the input image.
[image: Input Image]
This is the output I want.
[image: Output Image]

Please help me on how to get these results.
Thanks

Comment: above output can be achieved using bitwise AND operation of image with mask.

Comment: Please I want a brief explanation with code as I mentioned I'm a beginner in OpenCV it will very helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to create a mask like this

Comment: check this to create a circular mask https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d96/tutorial_basic_geometric_drawing.html

Comment: @user8190410 Thanks with your given link now I can create a mask Mat using input image size and draw a circle in mask Mat and what are the next steps?